# Azure Service Bus Relay and TrackingId: where to find more information on errors

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebusrelay

we are using [Azure Service Bus Relay](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-relay/) to connect to a on-premise intranet WCF service from a web site on the internet. It has been working fine for months.

Since yesterday the serice was not reachable from outside (bad gateway,  TrackingId:4a7a01ed-2059-4720-aba5-f61ee808a86e_G2). 
On the Azure Classic Portal I can see that see on-premise service is correctly registered to the Service Bus Infrastructure (it correctly show 1 Http listener to the service), so I'm suspecting something else...

Does anybody know where I can type my TrackingId and know more about the "inner error"?

I wasn't able to find anything on the Azure Portal and documentation on the matter is non-existent.

Is contacting Microsoft support the only way to have more info?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes support will be the only option for this and they will need this trackingid to find the exact issue.

Comment: I wonder if they will ever provide an automated way to query those TrackingIDs via Azure portal... That would simplify debugging a lot.

Comment: The tracking IDs correlate with back end logs.The SB team can use those logs to figure out what is causing the bad gateway.